# 2018 MathCounts: Let $D(k)$ be the number of diagonals for a polygon with $k$ sides. If $D(m) + D(n) = 125$, what is the value of $m+n$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

The question was asked in the 2018 Raytheon MATHCOUNTS National Competition. It appears in the video around the 35:34 mark:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSnOLW_W6og&t=2134

> Let $D(k)$ be the number of diagonals for a polygon with $k$ sides. If
>   $D(m) + D(n) = 125$, what is the value of $m+n$?

The formula for the number of diagonals is well-known and easily derived as $k(k-3)/2$.

I then computed several values, and found a suitable pair of numbers to solve the problem.

But is there any easier way to solve this equation:

$$\frac{n(n-3)}{2} + \frac{m(m-3)}{2} = 125$$
$$n,m \in {3, 4, ...}$$

The students were supposed to solve this in minutes without a calculator.

My guess is there is not a simpler way--in MathCounts the students may have just memorized many values.

Comment: One may need to use methods from Diophantine equations - guess I can't mind my decisions, hm?

Comment: The top MATHCOUNTS competitors would probably be able to make a table of values of $m(m-3)$ for $m = 1,2,\ldots,16$ and find 2 pairs which sum up to $250$ in under a minute. If this was part of the countdown round at the national competition, that means the two people trying to answer it are in the top 12 middle school students in the nation. So expecting them to solve this in 40 seconds seems a little tough, but it isn't that ridiculous.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: I think I see a trick now. Clearly $D(4) = 2$, and MATHCOUNTS competitors could then see $D(k + 1) - D(k) = k - 1$. So then $D(5) = D(4) + 3 = 5$, and then $D(6) = D(5) + 4 = 9$. It wouldn't be too hard to continue the table, though pretty crazy still for 1 minute. Diagonals are also a common problem topic, so perhaps $D(10) = 35$ and $D(15) = 90$ would just be memorized as facts.

Comment: I did have perfect squares up to about $36$ or so memorized when I did MATHCOUNTS, so someone memorizing the number of diagonals of a $k$-gon for several values of $k$ isn't that much crazier. Although, I'd personally think memorizing $\binom{k}{2}$ for several values of $k$ would be more useful than $D(k)$. The recursive trick you mentioned is clever. Under time pressure, I would not have thought of it, and would resort to multiplying $k(k-3)$ for every value of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=x-n$. Then,
$$\frac{n(n-3)}{2}+\frac{m(m-3)}{2}=125$$
is equivalent to
$$x^2-(2n+3)x+2n^2- 250 = 0$$
which implies
$$x=\frac{2n+3\pm\sqrt{1018-(2n-3)^2}}{2}$$

So, there has to be an integer $k$ such that $$1018=(2n-3)^2+k^2$$
Here, both $2n-3$ and $k$ are odd.

Since the rightmost digit of $(\text{odd})^2$ is either $1,9$ or $5$, both the rightmost digit of $(2n-3)^2$ and that of $k^2$ are $9$.

So, we only need to consider
$$3^2=9, 7^2=49, 13^2=169, 17^2=289, 23^2=529, 27^2=729$$

So, we see that 
$$27^2+17^2=1018$$
is the only possible sum.

So, $2n-3=27$ implies $n=15$, and $2n-3=17$ implies $n=10$.

Therefore, $$\color{red}{m+n=x=25}$$

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve $n^2-3n+m^2-3m = 250$ for $n,m\ge 3$.

Multiplying by $8$ and symmetrizing the polynomials, we get that the equation is equivalent to solving 
$$j^2-9 + k^2-9 = 1000,$$
with $j=2n-3$, $k=2m-3$, or 
$$j^2+k^2=1018.$$

Mod $3$ we have $$j^2+k^2\equiv 1\pmod{3},$$ so one of $j$ or $k$ is divisible by $3$. Without loss of generality then, $j=3x$. 
Now we want to solve 
$$9x^2 + k^2 =1018.$$
Mod $9$, we get 
$$k^2 \equiv 1\pmod{9}.$$ Then $k=9y+10$ or $9y+8$ for some $y>0$, since the units mod $9$ are cyclic.

Now we have either
$$9x^2 + 81y^2+180y+100 = 1018$$
which reduces to 
$$ x^2 + 9y^2 + 20y = 102$$
or 
$$9x^2+81y^2+144y + 64 = 1018,$$
which reduces to 
$$ x^2 + 9y^2 + 16y = 106$$
In either case, $1\le y\le 2$.

Thus we are reduced to computing four values less than $100$ and checking whether they are squares:

For $y=1$, computing
$102- (9y^2+20y)$ and $106-(9y^2+16y)$  gives 
 $102-29 = 73$, and $106-25 = 81$.

$81=9^2$, so we are already done without checking $y=2$. This gives $x=9$, $y=1$, corresponding to $j=27$, $k=17$, and thus $n=15$, $m=10$.

Checking our work yields 
$$15\cdot 6 + 5\cdot 7 = 90+35=125.$$